# how to make angular response to http 401

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-guards

I'm having a nodejs (express) as a server side and an angular 6 as client.In the server I have middlewear function that makes a session check. In case where the session is invalid or not exists, I would like to send a response to the client so that it can react to it. I thought of returning a response code of 401 from the server, and make some kind of listener\route-guard\HttpInterceptor  in the client, so - it can manage the situation in the client (redirect it to the login page, for example).
Here is my code in the server:

```
router.use('/', (req, res, next) =>
{
    if (!req.session.user)
    {
        res.status(401);
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
})
```

How can I catch\listen to this response in the angular app ?

Comment: Do you have any code of the request from your client?

Comment: Although you use Angular, this has nothing to do with, so I removed the tags. Consider adding tags such as [tag:node] or [tag:express].

Comment: @Maryannah, he asked "How can I catch\listen to this response in the angular app ?" I believe he is asking an angular-related question.

Comment: @Riv my bad, I focused on `I would like to send a response to the client so that it can react to it`. I'm adding the tags back, and your solution is [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication)

Comment: If you are talking about a 401 HTTP error then I suppose you would like to redirect your user to the login page if any of its requests are throwing a 401.

If it is the case I would suggest you to take a look at the HttpInterceptor interface & of course at the RxJS catchError

Comment: I've done something very similar here. You might to check it and get the idea [ErrorInterceptor](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/client/src/app/core/interceptor/error.interceptor.ts#L13)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an `HttpInterceptor` in which you can check wether status is 401, if yes then logout user and redirect to login page. What `HttpInterceptor` do is intercept every request and response and allow you to do some specific action like checking if servce returned 401 status. However be aware of `range` for `interceptor` it's working like `services` so if you include it in your top level module then it will intercept every request and response

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor( 
       private authService: AuthService
    ) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => event), // pass further respone
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                // here will be catched error from response, just check if its 401
                if (error && error.status == 401)
                    // then logout e.g. this.authService.logout()
                return throwError(error);
            }));
    }
}
```

And then include it in `app.httpmodule` in providers section

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true
  },
]
```

Read more at [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) or [angular.io guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Comment: Patryk Brejdak - this is the perfect solution for me, just what I was looking for !

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: Tried several interceptors from other Stack Answers and some blog sites, but this is the first that just works. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

There are two parameters present when you hit http calls . 
First :  the success callback . Second :  the error callback.

for example if we have a service named  `api` below will be the complete code :

if you need to capture the error in service:

```
 getData(){ 
  this._http.get(url).map((response: Response) =>{
     return response.json();    
   })
     .catch(this.handelError) 
}

handelError(error: Response){
   console.log('got below error from server',error);
}
```

If you need to capture error in component:

```
 someMethod(){

    this._apiService.getData().susbscribe((result)=>{
         console.log('sucess',result);
        // do further processing
    },(error)=>{
        console.log('error from service',error);
        // do further processing
     });
}
```

Comment: This is the basic methodology and behavior - I was looking for a solution with one point of treatment - this is due to the fact that it is related to a http 401 (unauthorize) error which is relevant to every request to the server. See Patryk Brejdak answer - it is perfect

Comment: @Guy E it was difficult to understand what you want exactly by looking at the amount of information you have provided in the question. However glad that your problem is solved.